# package org.apache.thrift does not exist

Tags: java, jar, import, thrift

I'm trying to write a basic java application that would use thrift. The thing I'm missing is a working jar file.

I've downloaded 0.8.0 gz version of thrift from the official website download pages and created the jar archive on my own (`jar cf thrift-0.8.0.jar src/org`). I've moved the new jar file into my project directory. Then, I've added this jar file manually to the project - I'm working in NetBeans IDE. Everything seems as it should work, but it doesn't - red error messages occur everywhere I want to use thrift libs. This is piece of my code:

```
package com.blogspot.symfonyworld.thrift;

import com.blogspot.symfonyworld.thrift.server.MainService;
import org.apache.thrift.TException;

public class MainServiceHandler implements MainService.Iface {

  @Override
    public int add(int n1, int n2) throws TException {
        return n1 + n2;
    }

    @Override
    public int sub(int n1, int n2) throws TException {
        return n1 + n2;
    }

}
```

and the other file:

```
/**
 * Autogenerated by Thrift Compiler (0.8.0)
 *
 * DO NOT EDIT UNLESS YOU ARE SURE THAT YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING
 *  @generated
 */
package com.blogspot.symfonyworld.thrift.server;

import org.apache.thrift.scheme.IScheme;
import org.apache.thrift.scheme.SchemeFactory;
import org.apache.thrift.scheme.StandardScheme;

import org.apache.thrift.scheme.TupleScheme;
import org.apache.thrift.protocol.TTupleProtocol;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.BitSet;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MainService {

  public interface Iface {

    public int add(int n1, int n2) throws org.apache.thrift.TException;

    public int sub(int n1, int n2) throws org.apache.thrift.TException;

  }

  public interface AsyncIface {

    public void add(int n1, int n2, org.apache.thrift.async.AsyncMethodCallback<AsyncClient.add_call> resultHandler) throws org.apache.thrift.TException;

    public void sub(int n1, int n2, org.apache.thrift.async.AsyncMethodCallback<AsyncClient.sub_call> resultHandler) throws org.apache.thrift.TException;

  }
```

When I run build, I get following errors:

```
ant -f /var/www/laughing-thrift-duck jar
init:
Deleting: /var/www/laughing-thrift-duck/build/built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: /var/www/laughing-thrift-duck/build/built-jar.properties
Compiling 2 source files to /var/www/laughing-thrift-duck/build/classes
/var/www/laughing-thrift-duck/src/com/blogspot/symfonyworld/thrift/MainServiceHandler.java:4: package org.apache.thrift does not exist
import org.apache.thrift.TException;
/var/www/laughing-thrift-duck/src/com/blogspot/symfonyworld/thrift/server/MainService.java:9: package org.apache.thrift.scheme does not exist
import org.apache.thrift.scheme.IScheme;
/var/www/laughing-thrift-duck/src/com/blogspot/symfonyworld/thrift/server/MainService.java:10: package org.apache.thrift.scheme does not exist
import org.apache.thrift.scheme.SchemeFactory;
/var/www/laughing-thrift-duck/src/com/blogspot/symfonyworld/thrift/server/MainService.java:11: package org.apache.thrift.scheme does not exist
import org.apache.thrift.scheme.StandardScheme;
/var/www/laughing-thrift-duck/src/com/blogspot/symfonyworld/thrift/server/MainService.java:13: package org.apache.thrift.scheme does not exist
import org.apache.thrift.scheme.TupleScheme;
/var/www/laughing-thrift-duck/src/com/blogspot/symfonyworld/thrift/server/MainService.java:14: package org.apache.thrift.protocol does not exist
import org.apache.thrift.protocol.TTupleProtocol;
# and many many more...
```

The main question is: **package org.apache.thrift does not exist** - how come?!

Can someone point me on what did I do wrong with importing a custom jar into my project? I think this has nothing to do with thrift precisely, but with importing jars in general.

Comment: Download Apache Thrift and put the jar in the classpath. If it's a web application, put it in `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I've downloaded 0.8.0 gz version of thrift from the official website download pages and created the jar archive on my own (jar cf thrift-0.8.0.jar src/org)

Why did you create your own jar? And why you created it with source files? A jar library must contain at least the bytecode classes, ready to be used.

You must let thrift compile itself into a jar and then use it:

- browse to `/lib/java`
- run `ant` in terminal
- check the build folder and you will see a `.jar`
- use that one

Answer (score 0):

When you use the command `jar cf thrift-0.8.0.jar src/org` to create the jar file, the classes for the org package (and under it) are stored in the src/org instead of org, so Java can't find it. Try to use this command instead `jar cf thrift-0.8.0.jar -C src org`, which should produce the correct structure.

You may verify it by running `jar tf thrift-0.8.0.jar` and see the content.